# Finding number of times each line in algorithm is executed

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I am somewhat confused as to how to complete this question. I included my work so far but I am still confused about it. Can anyone explain how to solve these types of questions?

[image: My work]

Comment: If you write this in a programming language (e.g. Python or Java) then you can step through it in a debugger, and actually count the lines using tally marks.

Comment: You have included your results, but not your work.  Most of all, how did you decide how many times you entered the if's "then" branch?

Comment: You seem to have answered the quoted exercise. *What* exactly is the problem then? Just saying *"confused"* is not a good problem statement.